# Jquery mouseenter Just apear on the second time

Tags: jquery

I have this script to show a balloon:

```
<script>
$("body").on('mouseenter', '.balloon', function(){
  $('.balloon').each(function(){
     $('.balloon').css( 'cursor', 'pointer' );
      $(this).balloon({
        url: '../functions/retorna-dados-instituicao.php?idInstituicao=' + $(this).attr('id'),
        position: "bottom",
        offsetX: -50,
        showDuration: 500,
        hideDuration: 0,
        tipSize: 0,
         css: {
          border: 'solid 2px #5baec0',
          padding: '10px',
          fontSize: '100%',
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          lineHeight: '1.5',
          opacity: 0.8,
          backgroundColor: '#666',
          color: '#fff'
        }
     });
   }); 
});
</script>
```

But the balloon appear just from the second time it is positioned on the element. How can I avoid this?

Comment: I dont understad the question, can you rephrase it? Also a working jsfiddle with a minimal example of the code that's not working would be nice. Thanks

Comment: The script shows a balloon when I position the mouse hover a element with the class ".balloon", but the ballon appear just when I position the mouse hover the elemente more than once. Sorry for my bad english!